# Can't change or return StringProperty in GAE db

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to run one page that changes the value of a variable and then run another that displays the value of that variable. Sounds simple enough, but I'm still very new to Python and GAE so I'm having difficulty figuring out why exactly the second page displays "none".

```
class Model(db.Model):
  variable = db.StringProperty()
  def change(self):
    self.variable = '123'
  def echo(self):
    return self.variable

class Change(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    model = Model(key_name = 'test')
    model.change()

class Echo(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    model = Model(key_name = 'test')
    self.response.out.write(model.echo())
```

Note: I am not receiving any errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the model instance in the Datastore using `put()` method & using `get_by_key_name` you can retrieves the model instance (or instances) for the given key name (or names)

```
class Model(db.Model):
    variable = db.StringProperty()
    def change(self):
       self.variable = '123'
       self.put()
    def echo(self):
       return self.variable

class Change(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
       model = Model(key_name = 'test')
       model.change()

class Echo(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def get(self):
       model = Model.get_by_key_name('test')
       self.response.out.write(model.echo())
```